# How do you use cookies and HTTP Basic Authentication in CherryPy?

Tags: python, session, authentication, cookies, cherrypy

I have a CherryPy web application that requires authentication. I have working HTTP Basic Authentication with a configuration that looks like this:

```
app_config = {
    '/' : {
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.sessions.name': 'zknsrv',
        'tools.auth_basic.on': True,
        'tools.auth_basic.realm': 'zknsrv',
        'tools.auth_basic.checkpassword': checkpassword,
        }
    }
```

HTTP auth works great at this point. For example, this will give me the successful login message that I defined inside `AuthTest`:

```
curl http://realuser:realpass@localhost/AuthTest/
```

Since sessions are on, I can save cookies and examine the one that CherryPy sets:

```
curl --cookie-jar cookie.jar http://realuser:realpass@localhost/AuthTest/
```

The `cookie.jar` file will end up looking like this:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

localhost       FALSE   /       FALSE   1348640978      zknsrv  821aaad0ba34fd51f77b2452c7ae3c182237deb3
```

However, I'll get an HTTP `401 Not Authorized` failure if I provide this session ID without the username and password, like this:

```
curl --cookie 'zknsrv=821aaad0ba34fd51f77b2452c7ae3c182237deb3' http://localhost/AuthTest
```

What am I missing?

Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, the short answer is *you can do this, but you have to write your own CherryPy tool* (a `before_handler`), and you *must not* enable Basic Authentication in the CherryPy config (that is, you shouldn't do anything like `tools.auth.on` or `tools.auth.basic...` etc) - you have to handle HTTP Basic Authentication yourself. The reason for this is that the built-in Basic Authentication stuff is apparently pretty primitive. If you protect something by enabling Basic Authentication like I did above, it will do that authentication check *before it checks the session*, and your cookies will do nothing.

### My solution, in prose

Fortunately, even though CherryPy doesn't have a way to do both built-in, you can still use its built-in session code. You still have to write your own code for handling the Basic Authentication part, but in total this is not so bad, and using the session code is a big win because writing a custom session manager is a good way to introduce security bugs into your webapp.

I ended up being able to take a lot of things from a page on the CherryPy wiki called [Simple authentication and access restrictions helpers](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/AuthenticationAndAccessRestrictions). That code uses CP sessions, but rather than Basic Auth it uses a special page with a login form that submits `?username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD`. What I did is basically nothing more than changing the provided `check_auth` function from using the special login page to using the HTTP auth headers.

In general, you need a function you can add as a CherryPy tool - specifically a `before_handler`. (In the original code, this function was called `check_auth()`, but I renamed it to `protect()`.) This function first tries to see if the cookies contain a (valid) session ID, and if that fails, it tries to see if there is HTTP auth information in the headers.

You then need a way to require authentication for a given page; I do this with `require()`, plus some *conditions*, which are just callables that return `True`. In my case, those conditions are `zkn_admin()`, and `user_is()` functions; if you have more complex needs, you might want to also look at `member_of()`, `any_of()`, and `all_of()` from the original code.

If you do it like that, you already have a way to log in - you just submit a valid session cookie or HTTPBA credentials to any URL you protect with the `@require()` decorator. All you need now is a way to log out.

(The original code instead has an `AuthController` class which contains `login()` and `logout()`, and you can use the whole `AuthController` object in your HTTP document tree by just putting `auth = AuthController()` inside your CherryPy root class, and get to it with a URL of e.g. http://example.com/auth/login and http://example.com/auth/logout. My code doesn't use an authcontroller object, just a few functions.)

### Some notes about my code

- Caveat: Because I wrote my own parser for HTTP auth headers, it only parses what I told it about, which means just HTTP Basic Auth - not, for example, Digest Auth or anything else. For my application that's fine; for yours, it may not be.
- It assumes a few functions defined elsewhere in my code: `user_verify()` and `user_is_admin()`
- I also use a `debugprint()` function which only prints output when a `DEBUG` variable is set, and I've left these calls in for clarity.
- You can call it `cherrypy.tools.WHATEVER` (see the last line); I called it `zkauth` based on the name of my app. Take care NOT to call it `auth`, or the name of any other built-in tool, though .
- You then have to enable `cherrypy.tools.WHATEVER` in your CherryPy configuration.
- As you can see by all the TODO: messages, this code is still in a state of flux and not 100% tested against edge cases - sorry about that! It will still give you enough of an idea to go on, though, I hope.

### My solution, in code

```
import base64
import re
import cherrypy 

SESSION_KEY = '_zkn_username'

def protect(*args, **kwargs):
    debugprint("Inside protect()...")

    authenticated = False
    conditions = cherrypy.request.config.get('auth.require', None)
    debugprint("conditions: {}".format(conditions))
    if conditions is not None:
        # A condition is just a callable that returns true or false
        try:
            # TODO: I'm not sure if this is actually checking for a valid session?
            # or if just any data here would work? 
            this_session = cherrypy.session[SESSION_KEY]

            # check if there is an active session
            # sessions are turned on so we just have to know if there is
            # something inside of cherrypy.session[SESSION_KEY]:
            cherrypy.session.regenerate()
            # I can't actually tell if I need to do this myself or what
            email = cherrypy.request.login = cherrypy.session[SESSION_KEY]
            authenticated = True
            debugprint("Authenticated with session: {}, for user: {}".format(
                    this_session, email))

        except KeyError:
            # If the session isn't set, it either wasn't present or wasn't valid. 
            # Now check if the request includes HTTPBA?
            # FFR The auth header looks like: "AUTHORIZATION: Basic <base64shit>"
            # TODO: cherrypy has got to handle this for me, right? 

            authheader = cherrypy.request.headers.get('AUTHORIZATION')
            debugprint("Authheader: {}".format(authheader))
            if authheader:
                #b64data = re.sub("Basic ", "", cherrypy.request.headers.get('AUTHORIZATION'))
                # TODO: what happens if you get an auth header that doesn't use basic auth?
                b64data = re.sub("Basic ", "", authheader)

                decodeddata = base64.b64decode(b64data.encode("ASCII"))
                # TODO: test how this handles ':' characters in username/passphrase.
                email,passphrase = decodeddata.decode().split(":", 1)

                if user_verify(email, passphrase):

                    cherrypy.session.regenerate()

                    # This line of code is discussed in doc/sessions-and-auth.markdown
                    cherrypy.session[SESSION_KEY] = cherrypy.request.login = email
                    authenticated = True
                else:
                    debugprint ("Attempted to log in with HTTBA username {} but failed.".format(
                            email))
            else:
                debugprint ("Auth header was not present.")

        except:
            debugprint ("Client has no valid session and did not provide HTTPBA credentials.")
            debugprint ("TODO: ensure that if I have a failure inside the 'except KeyError'"
                        + " section above, it doesn't get to this section... I'd want to"
                        + " show a different error message if that happened.")

        if authenticated:
            for condition in conditions:
                if not condition():
                    debugprint ("Authentication succeeded but authorization failed.")
                    raise cherrypy.HTTPError("403 Forbidden")
        else:
            raise cherrypy.HTTPError("401 Unauthorized")

cherrypy.tools.zkauth = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', protect)

def require(*conditions):
    """A decorator that appends conditions to the auth.require config
    variable."""
    def decorate(f):
        if not hasattr(f, '_cp_config'):
            f._cp_config = dict()
        if 'auth.require' not in f._cp_config:
            f._cp_config['auth.require'] = []
        f._cp_config['auth.require'].extend(conditions)
        return f
    return decorate

#### CONDITIONS
#
# Conditions are callables that return True
# if the user fulfills the conditions they define, False otherwise
#
# They can access the current user as cherrypy.request.login

# TODO: test this function with cookies, I want to make sure that cherrypy.request.login is 
#       set properly so that this function can use it. 
def zkn_admin():
    return lambda: user_is_admin(cherrypy.request.login)

def user_is(reqd_email):
    return lambda: reqd_email == cherrypy.request.login

#### END CONDITIONS

def logout():
    email = cherrypy.session.get(SESSION_KEY, None)
    cherrypy.session[SESSION_KEY] = cherrypy.request.login = None
    return "Logout successful"
```

Now all you have to do is enable both builtin sessions and your own `cherrypy.tools.WHATEVER` in your CherryPy configuration. Again, take care not to enable `cherrypy.tools.auth`. My configuration ended up looking like this:

```
config_root = {
    '/' : {
        'tools.zkauth.on': True, 
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.sessions.name': 'zknsrv',
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same problem and after just a couple little tweaks, this solved it very nicely!!