# Authenticating with Cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

[This page](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html#digest) of the CherryPy documentation contains the following snippet:

```
from cherrypy.lib import auth_digest

USERS = {'jon': 'secret'}

conf = {
   '/protected/area': {
        'tools.auth_digest.on': True,
        'tools.auth_digest.realm': 'localhost',
        'tools.auth_digest.get_ha1': auth_digest.get_ha1_dict_plain(USERS),
        'tools.auth_digest.key': 'a565c27146791cfb'
   }
}

cherrypy.quickstart(myapp, '/', conf)
```

What do the 4 item starting with `tools.auth_digest` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digest is an authentication mechanism that is slightly more secure than basic authentication, see the definition here [What is digest authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384230/what-is-digest-authentication)

I had a look through the CherryPy source to see if there was any kind of documentation on what the arguments meant, from [this file](http://svn.cherrypy.org/trunk/cherrypy/lib/auth_digest.py) it says that the arguments are:

```
realm
    A string containing the authentication realm.

get_ha1
    A callable which looks up a username in a credentials store
    and returns the HA1 string, which is defined in the RFC to be
    MD5(username : realm : password).  The function's signature is:
    ``get_ha1(realm, username)``
    where username is obtained from the request's 'authorization' header.
    If username is not found in the credentials store, get_ha1() returns
    None.

key
    A secret string known only to the server, used in the synthesis of nonces.
```

The `on` flag will (hopefully obviously) just enable digest authentication and the force it to search for digest parameters instead of basic auth parameters.

Note that the `get_ha1` parameter is a callable, from searching the file there are 3 versions:

```
get_ha1_dict_plain
get_ha1_dict
get_ha1_file_htdigest
```

There is appropriate docstrings on these functions if you want to see exactly how they work.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Yes, this helps, but... how do I get a link (for example `edit`) to appear or disappear on a page depending on whether the user is authenticated or what is his role/group/whatever?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not what your question asked for. This thread might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/13959574/3110529.

Comment: You are right, I didn't ask for it. I just hoped to get an answer with more details about the CherryPy authentication process. Thanks for your link.